# Oreo: How to listen unlock event?

Tags: android

I want to do some work when user unlock their phone

I define a receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".service.ScreenReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and Receiver

```
class ScreenReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

}

private fun checkClearSavedNote(context: Context) {
    AppPref.getInstance(context).putString(AppPref.KEY_ID_CURRENT_NOTE, "")
    Log.e("Quang", "clear note")
}
}
```

But it was not called when fired

I've tried using `Service` and `registerBroadcastReceiver` inside

and start it when application start

```
class MyApplication : MultiDexApplication() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance = this
    MultiDex.install(applicationContext)
        try {
            startService(Intent(this, NoteService::class.java))
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
}
```

}
but it work only with Android API < 8.0 because [background execution limit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `targetSdk < 26` to leverage implicit broadcasts. Otherwise you have to change your design according to latest list of exempted broadcasts.

Comment: If I can config device OS for my app, what should I do to listen this important event?